# How to write code in italic font in latex

Tags: latex

i want to write a full code in italics font in latex. I used \begin{listing}
 and typed the code and I got the code entered in normal font. But i need to enter the whole code in italics.The code is given below.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pathlib import Path

jpeg_images = list(Path(r'D:\plant\train').glob('**/*.jpg'))
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten() for file in jpeg_images])
folder = ['Black-grass', 'Charlock', 'Cleavers', 'Common Chickweed', 'Common wheat', 'Fat Hen', 'Loose Silky-bent',
      'Maize','Scentless Mayweed','Shepherds Purse', 'Small-flowered Cranesbill','Sugar beet']
Path = r'D:\plant\train'
for i in range(12):
    listing = os.listdir(Path+'/'+folder[i])
    for file in listing :
        image = cv2.imread(Path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file)

        imagee=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        plt.imshow(imagee)
```

Please help me with this. I need this whole code to be entered in italics in latex.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: loading the `listings` package and setting the `basicstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{
    basicstyle=\itshape
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pathlib import Path

jpeg_images = list(Path(r'D:\plant\train').glob('**/*.jpg'))
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten() for file in jpeg_images])
folder = ['Black-grass', 'Charlock', 'Cleavers', 'Common Chickweed', 'Common wheat', 'Fat Hen', 'Loose Silky-bent',
      'Maize','Scentless Mayweed','Shepherds Purse', 'Small-flowered Cranesbill','Sugar beet']
Path = r'D:\plant\train'
for i in range(12):
    listing = os.listdir(Path+'/'+folder[i])
    for file in listing :
        image = cv2.imread(Path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file)

        imagee=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        plt.imshow(imagee)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

`\textit{This sentence is in italics.}`

http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-italics.html

Comment: You cannot put fragile content, such as code ,in the argument of `\textit{}`

Comment: OK ROFL, thanks for your advice! and the downvote ofcourse ;)